# How to merge Hash of Hashes

Tags: ruby

I have two hashes.  How do I merge these two together into one hash?

```
hash_one = {3=>{"pre_event_sales_count"=>-12}}
hash_two = {3=>{"sold_count"=>-12}}
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
{3 => {"sold_count"=>-12, "pre_event_sales_count"=>-12}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the deep merge

```
require "active_support/core_ext/hash"
hash_one.deep_merge(hash_two)
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to provide proof that your code works.

Answer (score 1):

Traverse all keys of the first hash, and if a key exists in the second hash, merge it to the first:

```
hash_one.keys.each{ |k| hash_one[k].merge!(hash_two[k]) if hash_two[k] }
```

Now `hash_one` is: `{3=>{"pre_event_sales_count"=>-12, "sold_count"=>-12}}`

BTW, it's better to use symbols instead of strings for hash keys.

Comment: It's always a good idea to provide proof that your code works.

Answer (score 0):

```
hash_one.merge!(hash_two)
```

Will put `hash_two` into `hash_one` and overwrite any duplicates.

Comment: This won't prove the result the OP wants. It results in `{3=>{"sold_count"=>-12}}`.